# getting particular word from a row

Tags: java

how  to get the words(aaa,bbbb,ccc..etc) between OTHER and TREATED from these rows, OTHER and TREATED are common lines.i want to show only in between OTHER and TREATED words.

```
TABLE 5L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER aaaa TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 6L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER bbbbb  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 7L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER ccccc TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 8L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER dddddd  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 9L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER eeeee  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 10L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER ffffff  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 11L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER gggg  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 12L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER hhhh TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
TABLE 13L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER llll  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Try the following

```
String str="TABLE 5L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER aaaa TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 6L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER bbbbb  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 7L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER ccccc TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 8L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER dddddd  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 9L : ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER eeeee  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 10L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER ffffff  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 11L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER gggg  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 12L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER hhhh TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS." +
            "TABLE 13L: ESTIMATED AREA UNDER OTHER llll  TREATED WITH PSB BY SIZE GROUPS.";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("OTHER(.*?)TREATED");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

The Regular Expression will search for any String in between `"OTHER"` and `"TREATED"`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have read the line you could split the string. You need to use a Stringarray

```
Stringarray = String.split("OTHER ")
Endresult = Stringarray[1].split(" TREATED")
```

Endresult[0] will be you aaaa bbbb cccc or whatever is in between

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String w = str.replaceAll(".+ OTHER (.+) TREATED .+", "$1");
```

this means replace the whole string with contents of group 1 which is expression in parenthesis

Comment: You should also explain what is that, what you did and why, if someone isn't familiar with regexes he will not understand how your answer works :)